# WooCommerce Memberships - List Product Restrictions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need an array of all of the membership plans linked to a product, restricting its content. I can only find functions that list all plans, or plans a user currently has, or check a user against a given plan, but no way to check if a user has access to content of a specific product, dynamically.

[image: The below screenshot shows the information I'm trying to retrieve.]

Answer (score 0):

The below seemed to work just fine.

```html
if ( wc_memberships_is_product_purchasing_restricted() ) {

  $has_access = current_user_can( 'wc_memberships_purchase_restricted_product', $productID );

  if ( $has_access ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

}
```